# Removing a block of text from all files in a directory

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have 100 files in a directory of type .json. In these files I have a following block in all files

```
      "bind_dev": [
        "eth0",
        "bond0"
      ],
```

I want to remove this block from all the files with .json extension. How can this be done using linux shell?

```
{
  "name": "wnx_production",
  "description": "Wellnext",
  "cookbook_versions": {
    "fms-base": "= 1.0.49",
    "fms-zabbix": "= 0.1.35",
    "linuxad_auth": "= 0.2.75",
    "itcs104_bundle": "= 0.3.23",
    "policy_all_deep_security": "= 0.1.17",
    "fms-pdns": "= 0.1.38",
    "fms-yum": "= 0.1.17",
    "tscm": "= 1.0.29",
    "sudo": "= 2.7.10"
  },
  "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
  "chef_type": "environment",
  "default_attributes": {
    "satellite-client": {
      "capsule": {
        "capsule_name": "dal13ammcaps01.imzcloud.ibmammsap.local"
      }
    },
    "kickstart_ip": "146.89.142.214",
    "tscm": {
      "kickstart_ip": "146.89.142.214",
      "bind_dev": [
        "eth0",
        "bond0"
      ],
      "server_ip": "169.55.192.110",
      "proxy_ip": "169.55.28.46",
      "installer_url": "http://146.89.142.214/post_data/pkg/tivoliscm/"
    },
    "sudo": {
      "include_sudoers_d": false,
      "suroot_alias": "SUROOT"
    },
    "itcs104_bundle": {
      "gem_source": {
        "ssl_verify": false,
        "clear": true
      }
    },
    "sshd_config": {
      "permitrootlogin": "without-password"
    },
    "chef-client-12": {
      "chef-client-location": "http://146.89.142.214/post_data/pkg/chef"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the best way to manipulate JSON data from the shell. Here's how you could use it to process each file:

```
for file in *.json; do
    jq 'del(.default_attributes.tscm.bind_dev)' "$file" > "$file.tmp" &&
        mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't use sed for this. Personally I'd write it in Perl, but that's not what you asked.

Second, test this carefully, and by *carefully* I mean take a backup of the whole setup first, then run it a few times and see that it's doing all of what you want, and only what you want. (Again, use Perl...but since you asked...)

```
sed -r -n '/^\s*"bind_dev"\s*:.*/,/],/d' *.json
```

That's simplistic. Better to add more detail to the regex, but sometimes too much will make it miss things, where not enough will make it remove things you didn't want lost.

c.f.: [this guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) to extended sed regexes, and good luck.